# Multiple vlookup using index and match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I need to make a vlookup function based on two unique IDs. So far the Internet has told me that a combined match index will do the trick. Unfortunately are my excels skills limiting me.

Basically I have 3 different tabs. In tab1 I have a col with dates and one with quantities. These are the cols I need to lookup. In tab2 I have dates and a supplier name, while Im in tab3 got quantity information and a supplier name.

So I wish to match the information in tab2 and tab3 with tab1 so I can see when a supplier delivered a given quantity.

Comment: any date has only 0 or 1 supplier? So the quantity on a given date is for that supplier only? If that is not the case, your data set is incomplete to get the result you want.

Comment: @K_B I only have one supplier per date. The qty/date combination is unique for every supplier

Comment: tab3 already has the supplier name and the quantity, so what are you looking to get? and in what format?

Comment: @K_B I can try in other words. From tab2 I know when a supplier delivered. From tab3 I know how much a supplier delivered, but not when it happened. So I need to know when a supplier delivered a given quantity. Does that make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get Supplier / Date / Quantity. I guess the original idea of the problem as you set it out is overcomplicating things.

I would personally use the table with Supplier / Date on tab2 as the starting point and add a column with a formula to that tab to get the quantity. This formula will refer to `tab1` and will work perfectly fine with just a vlookup on the date and retrieve the quantity:

So on tab2 column C (specifically cell C2):

```
=VLOOKUP(A2 ; tab1!A:B ; 2 ; FALSE)
```

Or if you need comma as separator:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2 , tab1!A:B , 2 , FALSE)
```

Comment: Cheers mate.. Thank was very kind of you.